# What do you do if your colleague tells your mom that you got fired but your boss hasn't told you themselves?

Tags: legal, rights

My boyfriend recently got fired from work but nobody told him as they told me and his mom instead and it wasn't even the manager who said anything it was his colleague, how would we go about solving this?

Comment: How did your boyfriend get "fired" without anyone telling him? That sounds just like Milton from Office Space (except that they didn't tell his girlfriend or mom in the movie).

Comment: "I don't know where he got that idea,  Mom.  Nobody has said anything to me about it, and as far as I know they like my work. You know how bad the rumor mill can be. If anything does happen I'll let you know; until then I'm really not worried. Or whatever version of this seems appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

Your boyfriend isn't fired until his boss tells him he's fired. As far as we know, this could be the colleague making some rather tasteless joke. So do nothing rash; his boss might not even know about this "firing".

Now *if* the boss didn't even have the courage to tell him face to face but sent a colleague, and the colleague didn't have the courage either but told you and his mum instead, then I'd say your boyfriend will surely find a job with a better company.

Answer (score 4):

Your boyfriend should confront the colleague, and then ask the boss. In that order. Because the colleague might have been lying. Either way that's the guy I'd go and see first if I was your boyfriend, the colleague has no business talking to my mother or girlfriend.

Neither does the boss really.

Comment: I would suggest going to the boss first. If the other guy was lying, he needs to be disciplined and OP is not in position to do it. If he wasn't lying, this makes things even more awkward.

Comment: @AlexP If someone was giving false information to my mother and girlfriend, I'd be disciplining him myself. Some places you just don't go, he'd have a few seconds to explain himself, and he'd need a bloody good explanation.

Comment: @AlexP Just wondering, what if the other guy wasn't lying? "Boss, this guy told my mom and girlfriend I am fired." Boss: "Yeah, so?"

Comment: @MaskedMan then 1) you now know the truth and 2) if the manager is any good he will properly discipline the employee for this extreme lack of judgement.

Comment: @MaskedMan: If that happens, you are not fired. You are not fired unless you are told so, and the boss clearly didn't tell you.